# Nicanor Parra line: "Nothing important is learned from books. (I read this in a book.)"

Tags: poetry, quote-source, spanish-language, nicanor-parra

This is one of [Parra](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicanor_Parra)'s "anti-poems" but I can't recall the exact wording, or which book it appeared in, and can't seem to find it online. The poem says something along the lines of

> Nothing important is learned from books. (I read this in a book.)

Q: What is the actual Parra poem?

*Ideally the answer will feature the Spanish text.*

Comment: I can't help you with the poem, but it echoes Thomas Carlyle's dictum: Books are a Triviality. Life alone is Great.

Comment: @Mick Awesome!  No doubt Parra was referencing Carlyle.